# Crop multiple images to match them up in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have multiple partial screen shots of the same window. But since I created each of them at different times and since the I manually chose the select-area each time, the images don't line up.

I want to, for example, be able to open up one of the images in any "image preview" program and scroll through the images without them "jumping" left/right/up/down because of my inconsistent screen captures.

So, what's the quickest way to get the images to match up?

More:
The images all are mostly identical, with just a few parts changing from image to image. I need them all to match up so that when I look through them, the changed parts are obvious and so I don't get nauseated with all the jumping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get your images into Photoshop layers, open Bridge, select the images you want and go to Tools>Photoshop>Load into Photoshop Layers.

Choose Edit > Auto-Align Layers and select Auto as the alignment option. If Auto does not create good registration of your layers, try the Reposition option.

Use the crop tool to crop all the layers at once.

Now, go to File>Scripts>Export Layers to files...

Comment: Totally missed the auto-align option! Thanks for the info, Amy.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you. I just tested it and it is perfect. Sorry it took me a year to upvote and checkmark it. I rarely use this stack site, but was just notified that this question reached "popular" status. I was using a completely different (not visual) approach to solving this problem but might now go back to this one.

Comment: Tip: make sure to have the layers selected before doing Edit->Auto-Align

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the workflow you're going for here but ...

1. Pick any one of the screen shots and open it in P'shop.
2. Crop it to the minimum area that will accomodate all the screen
   caps.
3. Drop all the other shots onto a layer in that doc.
4. Use transparency to get them to overlay just so.
5. If you want them in separate files, export each layer so they are
   all on the same canvas size.

Comment: So there's no way that photoshop can automatically align the images in a layer?